# Javascript assignment between two select lists not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project in where I have two `selectlists`: one that is displayed to the user, and one that is hidden that contains my viewdata that the displayed one pulls from.

My Javascript function that triggers onchange for another `selectlist` is as follows:

```
function select()
    {
        document.getElementById("SelectedServer").innerHTML = document.getElementById("ServerSelect").value;
        var services = document.getElementById("ServiceSelect");
        services.options = serviceoptions.options;
        console.log(services.options === serviceoptions.options)
        var servers = document.getElementById("ServerSelect").selectedOptions;
        for (i = 0; i < services.length; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < servers.length; j++)
            {
                    if (services.options[i].value == servers.item(j).value) { }
                    else (services.options[i] = null)
            }
        }
    }
```

This function updates a text field with the selected servers, assigns my services `selectlist` with the options from the hidden data `selectlist` called "serviceoptions", and then sorts it so that the services are displayed only if they match the selected server (using `value`).

For some reason, when I do my options assignment (`services.options = serviceoptions.options;`), it runs without errors but clearly does not assign the options correctly.

The console output I put to test returns false, and chrome debugger shows that the length has not been updated.

I want to assign the options variable of `serviceoptions` to the options variable of `services`. Why can I not do this?

The issue I'm trying to solve with the hidden field is that before, my services would correctly disappear if they did not match, but I had no way to bring them back if the user selected another server.

I cannot use ajax to make another API call to retrieve the servers/services again.

Comment: [Select `options` property is read only you cannot set it](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#htmlselectelement). You need to add the options manually, ie through appendChild() or similar manner

Comment: @PatrickEvans That's unfortunate. Any way around it? Or even just setting one object to a copy of the other before working on it?